# select_related Как вывести модель к которой привязана другая модель по ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Django version 1.10

```
class Game(models.Model):
    game_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_set", default=2, blank=True, null=True)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="away_set", default=2, blank=True, null=True)


class GameCoefficient(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, default=3)
    win_type = models.CharField(choices=win_type, max_length=250,  blank=True, null=True, default="")
    value = models.FloatField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, default="")


class BaseView(View):
    data = dict()
    template = "index.html"
    def get(self, request):
        self.data['coefficents_and_game'] = GameCoefficient.objects.all().select_related('game')
        return render_to_response(self.template, self.data)
```

При рендеринге я получаю GameCoefficient и ForeignKey GAME при этом template получает по GameCoefficient модели и если делать

```
{% for item in coefficents_and_game %}
     {{item.game}} 
{% endfor %}
```

в этом случае код игр(game_code) повторяется по количеству  GameCoefficient а мне нужно **ОДНИМ** запросом вывести Game и GameCoefficient. Но по Game таблице связанные с этой таблицей GameCoefficient.

```
{% for game in coefficents_and_game %}
     {{game.game_code}}
     {% for coefficient in game %} 
            {{coefficient.win_type}}
            {{coefficient.value}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

По тому что читал это можно сделать одним из этих операторов "select_related" "fetch_reverse_relations" "prefetch_related" ну до конца не смог понять разницу между ними, что бы добиться результата и вывести в обратном порядке примера запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select_related` нужно использовать у кверисета модели, в которой указан `ForeingKey`, т.е. при связи многие к одному, на стороне многих. `prefetch_related` работает наоборот, на стороне одного подтягивает все связанные объекты, так же его можно использовать при связи многие ко многим.

```
Team.objects.prefetch_related('home_set')
Game.objects.select_related('home_team')
```

Оба этих метода можно использовать, для захвата связей связанных моделей.
В вашем случае, чтобы захватить все 3 таблицы можно использовать такой кверисет:

```
self.data['coefficents_and_game'] = GameCoefficient.objects.select_related('game__home_team', 'game__away_team')
```

Так к ним можно обращаться в шаблоне:

```
{% for game in coefficents_and_game %}
     {{ game.win_type }}
     {{ game.value }}
     {% for coefficient in game.game %} 
        {{ coefficient.game_code }}
        # Можно добавить еще один внутренний цикл 
        # по ключам home_team и away_team
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```